# Cleanning urls with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i am trying to use RewriteRules to get clean urls using my HTACCESS file.

here is what i have so far

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

The above code takes a url that looks like this company.com/about.php and turns it into company.com/about/ so all my links url are like this "/about/" i didnt add the .php because of the rewrite rule.

what i am trying to do now is add a rule that will clean my url when parameter is passed. for example
company.com/about/?profile=member_name i want it to look like company.com/about/member_name

i have tried the two rewrite code below but it doesn't work.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /our_work.php/ [L]
RewriteRule ^/our_work.php([^/\.]+)/?$ ?project=$1 [L]
```

please keep in mind that my file extension is already being striped from the url.

Please help

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Apache provides documentation on the use of [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) that you should read before proceeding.

In this particular case, you can rewrite `/about/{member_name}` to `/about.php?profile={member_name}` by implementing this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^about/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(/)?$ about.php?profile=$1 [L]
```

The rule states: The requested URL must begin with `about/` and be followed by letters and numbers (match #1) and may be proceeded by an additional ending forward slash (match #2); and it will be substitued with a URL `about.php` with `profile` query string's value as match #1. The `L` flag indicates that any rules that follow this rule should be ignored.

Attempting to "cascade" rules will not work with your current set of rules because the `/about/{...}` is not matched by the first rule.

Comment: you say that attempting to cascade rules will not work with the current set of rules i have. how would you set it up to accomplish my goal?